# Merging Columns using distinct ID number

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have extracted the table below using the formular stated below, because I want to use the table as a visual;

Active Ticket Table = CALCULATETABLE(Tickets,Tickets[value.statecode@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue]="Active")

As seen in the table there are duplicate data in the Value.TicketNumber, ProjectName & StatusCode, which I could have used remove duplicate data to remove. However, the RequestType column has distinct request Types.

[see details of the table using this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo5ZI.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo5ZI.png)

Whih formula can i use to make the Active intakes table appear as seen below please either in the visual or in the table

[this is how i want the table to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHny7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHny7.png)

Thank you in advance for your help

I do not know how to write the formula, so I haven't tried. Please I would appreciate if anyone can help me with a formula to achieve this